# Error in dimnames(s$v) <- list(colnames(x), paste0("PC", j)) : error length of dimnames 2 not equal to array extent

Tags: r, rstudio

When I run this code line

```
library(rENA)
category.data <- readr::read_csv("/home/Exemplo.csv")
category.set  <- create.ena.set(category.data)
```

It generates this error:

> Error in dimnames(s$v) <- list(colnames(x), paste0("PC", j)) :
>   error length of dimnames 2 not equal to array extent

This is the method:

```
create.ena.set <- function(data) {
    accum <- ena.accumulate.data(
                           units        = data[,c("UserId","DiscussionID"), drop=F],
                           conversation = data[,c("UserId","DiscussionID"), drop=F],
                           metadata     = NULL,
                           codes        = data[, colnames(data)[-c(1:8)]],
                           weight.by = "binary")
    ena.make.set(enadata=accum)
}
```

I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Nor do we. Wanna tell us where `ena.make.set` and `ena.accumulate.data` come from? Have you tried `options(error=recover)`?

Comment: Sorry,  from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rENA/index.html

Comment: Could you include a small example of your csv file? Otherwise your code is not reproducible..

Comment: col ("PostId" ,  "ParentId" ,  "DiscussionID" , "UserId"  , "CreatedDate"  , "Topic" , "Message",  "Class",  "Class0" , "Class1" , "Class2" ," Class3" , "Class4"   line[1]: (2,  33, 5,  123, 11111, 50,   "Helllo! World", 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)  line[2]: (3,  36, 5,  122, 11111, 50,   "Helllo! Alien", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)  line[3]: (4,  36, 5,  120, 11111, 50,   "Helllo! My friend", 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)   line[4]: (6,  36, 5,  12, 11111, 50,   "Helllo! My friend", 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)